# EJB and JPA Class Format Error

Tags: jpa, ejb

hello iam trying to add a object to my database in n my web application and i get the following  exception  java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate field name&signature in class file Entity/Rpxfornecedor_. This the code of the Entity Rpxfornecedor:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rpxfornecedor")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Rpxfornecedor.findAll", query = "SELECT r FROM Rpxfornecedor r"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Rpxfornecedor.findByFid", query = "SELECT r FROM Rpxfornecedor r WHERE r.fid = :fid"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Rpxfornecedor.findByFNome", query = "SELECT r FROM Rpxfornecedor r WHERE r.fNome = :fNome"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Rpxfornecedor.findByFDescri\u00e7\u00e3o", query = "SELECT r FROM Rpxfornecedor r WHERE r.fDescri\u00e7\u00e3o = :fDescri\u00e7\u00e3o"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Rpxfornecedor.findByFNTel", query = "SELECT r FROM Rpxfornecedor r WHERE r.fNTel = :fNTel"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Rpxfornecedor.findByFNCel", query = "SELECT r FROM Rpxfornecedor r WHERE r.fNCel = :fNCel"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Rpxfornecedor.findByFEndere\u00e7o", query = "SELECT r FROM Rpxfornecedor r WHERE r.fEndere\u00e7o = :fEndere\u00e7o"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Rpxfornecedor.findByFEmail", query = "SELECT r FROM Rpxfornecedor r WHERE r.fEmail = :fEmail"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Rpxfornecedor.findByFFax", query = "SELECT r FROM Rpxfornecedor r WHERE r.fFax = :fFax"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Rpxfornecedor.findByFActivo", query = "SELECT r FROM Rpxfornecedor r WHERE r.fActivo = :fActivo"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Rpxfornecedor.findByFDataAct", query = "SELECT r FROM Rpxfornecedor r WHERE r.fDataAct = :fDataAct"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Rpxfornecedor.findByFDataNAct", query = "SELECT r FROM Rpxfornecedor r WHERE r.fDataNAct = :fDataNAct")})
public class Rpxfornecedor implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 80)
    @Column(name = "FID")
    private String fid;
    @Size(max = 80)
    @Column(name = "FNome")
    private String fNome;
    @Size(max = 1000)
    @Column(name = "FDescri\u00e7\u00e3o")
    private String fDescrição;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "FNTel")
    private String fNTel;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "FNCel")
    private String fNCel;
    @Size(max = 200)
    @Column(name = "FEndere\u00e7o")
    private String fEndereço;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "FEmail")
    private String fEmail;
    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "FFax")
    private String fFax;
    @Column(name = "FActivo")
    private Character fActivo;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 200)
    @Column(name = "FDataAct")
    private String fDataAct;
    @Size(max = 200)
    @Column(name = "FDataNAct")
    private String fDataNAct;

    public Rpxfornecedor() {
    }

    public Rpxfornecedor(String fid) {
        this.fid = fid;
    }

    public Rpxfornecedor(String fid, String fDataAct) {
        this.fid = fid;
        this.fDataAct = fDataAct;
    }

    public String getFid() {
        return fid;
    }

    public void setFid(String fid) {
        this.fid = fid;
    }

    public String getFNome() {
        return fNome;
    }

    public void setFNome(String fNome) {
        this.fNome = fNome;
    }

    public String getFDescrição() {
        return fDescrição;
    }

    public void setFDescrição(String fDescrição) {
        this.fDescrição = fDescrição;
    }

    public String getFNTel() {
        return fNTel;
    }

    public void setFNTel(String fNTel) {
        this.fNTel = fNTel;
    }

    public String getFNCel() {
        return fNCel;
    }

    public void setFNCel(String fNCel) {
        this.fNCel = fNCel;
    }

    public String getFEndereço() {
        return fEndereço;
    }

    public void setFEndereço(String fEndereço) {
        this.fEndereço = fEndereço;
    }

    public String getFEmail() {
        return fEmail;
    }

    public void setFEmail(String fEmail) {
        this.fEmail = fEmail;
    }

    public String getFFax() {
        return fFax;
    }

    public void setFFax(String fFax) {
        this.fFax = fFax;
    }

    public Character getFActivo() {
        return fActivo;
    }

    public void setFActivo(Character fActivo) {
        this.fActivo = fActivo;
    }

    public String getFDataAct() {
        return fDataAct;
    }

    public void setFDataAct(String fDataAct) {
        this.fDataAct = fDataAct;
    }

    public String getFDataNAct() {
        return fDataNAct;
    }

    public void setFDataNAct(String fDataNAct) {
        this.fDataNAct = fDataNAct;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (fid != null ? fid.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Rpxfornecedor)) {
            return false;
        }
        Rpxfornecedor other = (Rpxfornecedor) object;
        if ((this.fid == null && other.fid != null) || (this.fid != null && !this.fid.equals(other.fid))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Entity.Rpxfornecedor[ fid=" + fid + " ]";
    }

}
```

The error occurs in the following code:

```
public Rpxfornecedor addfornecedor(String Id, String nome, String endereço, String email, String cell, String tel, String fax, String des, String dnow){
     Rpxfornecedor Forn = new Rpxfornecedor();


     //em.flush();
     Forn.setFid(Id);
     Forn.setFNome(nome);
     Forn.setFEndereço(endereço);
     Forn.setFEmail(email);
     Forn.setFNCel(cell);
     Forn.setFNTel(tel);  
     Forn.setFFax(fax); 
     Forn.setFDescrição(des); 
     Forn.setFActivo('Y');
     Forn.setFDataAct(dnow);
     Forn.setFDataNAct("fbedfdf");     

     if(Forn != null){
      em.persist(Forn);  
      //em.persist(Forn);      
     }


     return Forn;
    }
```

So please any advice will be appreciated.

The JPA implementation that I am using is EclipseLink 2.0. I tried changing the jpa but i still got the same problem on every single one that come with netbeans 7.0.1.

Comment: Which JPA implementation are you using? Maybe you noticed the trailing underscore on the entity name in the error message, that means the error is in the meta model class that gets generated during compilation by the jpa provider. Looks like a bug in the jpa provider to me.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out I change the name of my fields in the database and the entity to fix it. ex:

```
@Column(name = "FDescri\u00e7\u00e3o")
```

should be

```
@Column(name = "FDescricao")
```